# Need help creating a dynamically updating score in pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame, blackjack

I'm intigrating my text based blackjack game with pygame. I can't seem to make the total of the player's hand update. Every time it justs adds it over the previous text, and it becomes impossible to read.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
def update(player, comp):
drawText('Money: $%s' % (money), font, windowSurface, 50, 30)
drawText('Press "H" to hit. Press S to stand', font2, windowSurface, 500, (30))
drawText('Player Total: %s' % (sumHand(player)), font2, windowSurface, 500, (50))
drawText('Dealer Total: %s' % (sumHand(comp)), font2, windowSurface, 650, (50))
pygame.display.update()


        while True:
        update(player, comp)
        mainClock.tick(FPS)
        if sumHand(player) < 22:
            pygame.display.update()
            hCount += 1
            print('Your cards are: %s with a total value of %d' % (player,sumHand(player))) #old
            print('The dealers visible card is %s' % (comp)) #old
            print('Hit or Stand?') #old
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                event = waitForPlayerToPressKey()
                if event.key == ord('h') and hCount == 0:
                    player.append(getCard(cards))
                    cardPrint3(player)
                    update(player, comp)
                elif event.key == ord('h') and hCount == 1:
                    player.append(getCard(cards))
                    cardPrint4(player)
                    update(player, comp)
                elif event.key == ord('h') and hCount == 2:
                    player.append(getCard(cards))
                    cardPrint5(player)
                    update(player, comp)
                elif event.key == ord('h') and hCount == 3:
                    player.append(getCard(cards))
                    cardPrint6(player)
                    update(player, comp)
                    break
                    money+=500
                else:
                    break
            else:
                break
```

Here is a pastebin of the full program if I missed something important.
http://pastebin.com/70EhteQ1

Answer (score 1):

You need to "clear" the screen, or at least the relevant portions of it, before you start drawing again.  Otherwise you are just drawing over the existing drawing.  Try this at the top of your loop:

```
while True:
    windowSurface.fill((255, 255, 255)) # this will draw over the entire screen surface with white
    update(player, comp)
    ...
```

Comment: How to I do that so it only does that to a certain portion of the screen?

Comment: Every time you call a surface's `blit()` function, a `Rect` is returned.  If you keep track of those, you can draw over only the relevant portions of the screen, although the code for that can get complicated.  Also, `pygame.display.update()` accepts a list of `Rects` as an argument, which allows you to only redraw those areas (although you still need to clear those sections before drawing anything on them if you don't want "trails" or jumbled-up text).

Comment: Honestly, if you don't have a known performance issue to deal with, I would suggest you just clear the entire screen each frame and re-draw all of your components.  It will be a lot less headache for you.